# How to make an ice lake with the Principled Shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I know back in the day you would just use a Glossy Shader and mix in surface imperfections. I'm trying to do it now with the Principled Shader and the only way it seems to work is if I turn the Metallic setting to 1 but wouldn't that be incorrect as it's not a metal? I'm trying to achieve something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Final:

[image: final]

### Node setup & overview:

First of all you want to have **Roughness** value to be pretty low. I've used procedural **Roughness map**, but without it value around **0.05** will give good results. This is based on the ice you want to make.

Secondly, don't forget that clear ice is transparent, you'll need to add **Transmission** (like for glass). It don't need to be fully 1.0. Also ice has **IOR value 1.309**, I've forgot to change it.

[image: nodes]